# return an even number Recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I need to write a Recursion function which takes in integer as input and returns the concatenation of the EVEN digits of the input number, i.e., we should remove the odd digits.

for example:

Creator(1234);
return number: 24.

Creator(459876);
return number: 486.

Well I'm pretty stuck in a dead end. I don't know how to return the right numbers.

That's my code I don't even know if I'm in the right way so.

My code:

```
int Creator(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    if ((n % 10) % 2 != 0)
        Creator(n / 10);

    return n % 10;

}
```

Comment: In the recursive call to `Creator`, what do you do with the value it *returns*?

Comment: A recursive call to Creator would return something like `return Creator(n % 10)`

Comment: Can you do it without recursion?

Comment: the all point is to study recursion functios so...

Comment: Yes, but if you can get the basic algorithm to work without recursion, you can convert it to use recursion later. That way you don't have to solve two problems at once.

Comment: and i really dont even know how to continu in this, i dont know how can i return a difrent number that chage each time?!?

Comment: `if (n == 0) return;` can't be right. You've got to return *something*.

Comment: thats my problem i dont know what to return and how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int Creator(int n){
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;//You must always return a value.
    if (n % 2 != 0)
        return Creator(n / 10);
    return Creator(n / 10) * 10 + n % 10;//It is necessary to accumulate the call result.
}
```

Comment: you are a genius! works perfect ! i have a question because i want to understand , how the function return the value and not changing it each time?

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga I may not understand exactly what you want to ask. You can change `Creator` as follows. `int Creator(int n, int accumulater, int mul10 ){
    if (n == 0)
        return accumulater;`

Comment: no i meant that i dont understand the last row in your code, how its accumulate the result and not changing it?

Comment: if You get sequence of `2,4`, 2*10 + 4 ==> 24. (Results already obtained)*10 + (Current one-digit trailing)